# Why won't my C program list the multiples of 7?

Tags: c

The goal of the program is to find the multiples of 7 in the range of "input_value_1" through "input_value_2". I'm confused as to why it only displays certain numbers...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int input_value_1;
int input_value_2;
int multiples[] = {};
int i = 0;
int count = 0;
int y;

printf("Enter a value:\n");
scanf("%i", &input_value_1);
printf("\nEnter a second value:\n");
scanf("%i", &input_value_2);

if(input_value_2 <= input_value_1)
{printf("Invalid Entry\n");}
else
{
    for(y = input_value_1;y <= input_value_2; y++)
    {
        if(y%7 == 0)
        {
            multiples[i] = y;
            i++;
            count++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=count; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", multiples[i]);
    }
}

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `multiples` is segfault waiting to happen.

Comment: you should really initialize that array to something that can actually hold your data, and not a constant size 0 array on the stack

Answer (score 2):

```
int multiples[100];
```

should fix it. Also, i< count at the display.

Answer (score 0):

Probably should set max length and initialize the array multiples[] before trying to set it's elements...

e.g.

```
int multiples[100] = { 0 };
```

You'll also want to stop setting elements when reaches count 100, i.e

```
for(y = input_value_1;y <= input_value_2 && count < 100; y++) {  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's one thing about your code that bothers me a little bit.

I don't know if the following line allocates your `multiples` array: (my c syntax is rusty)

```
int multiples[] = {};
```

but, I'm pretty sure that that line doesn't give it an indefinite amount of memory. at the very least.

My intuition says that if you enter a large enough range, you'll get a segmentation fault very fast.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should at least initialize multiples to certain size or even avoid using it.
Second, you have another bug in your code:

```
for(i=0; i<=count; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", multiples[i]);
    }
```

should be:

```
for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", multiples[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The range from input_value_1 to input_value_2 maybe very large.
The multiples of 7 may exceeds your array size.
The better way should use vector for storing

```
std::vector<int> multiples;
for(y = input_value_1;y <= input_value_2; y++)
    if(y%7 == 0)
        multiples.push_back(y);
for(i=0; i<=multiples.size(); i++)
    printf("%i\n", multiples[i]);
```

Or print it directly.

```
    for(y = input_value_1;y <= input_value_2; y++)
    {
        if(y%7 == 0)
            printf("%d\n", y);
    }
```